# Compressing many folders

Tags: bash, scripts, compression

I have a directory containing plenty of folders as well as compressed files. I need to compress the folders that are not already so (tar -cvzf ...) but have no experience in sh scripts.
Can anyone help me writing such a script please?

Comment: just tar the entire directory, what makes you think you need a script ?

Comment: @bodhi some of the folders in here are already tarred.. Wouldnt that cause issues if you just tried to tar the intire thing?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The main folder is too big to tar directly (500Gb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a script; the following command-line is enough:

```
for dir in */; do tar cvzf "${dir%*/}".tar.gz "$dir"/; done
```

Comment: Does it take into account that there are already tarred directories in the folder?

Comment: @Seth The OP didn't specified clear if he have folders and archives of those folders in the current directory.

Comment: In the solution from Radu, find might return respective to current path like "./dir1". In that case you can use <code> $(find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name [^\.]\* | sed 's:^\./::') </code> which will return just directory name.

Comment: Yes he did, read the question again.

Comment: what does the "${dir%*/}" do?

Comment: @Seth It is not clear: *"I have a directory containing plenty of folders as well as compressed files"*... So who knows if the compressed files are archives of those plenty of folders?!? Anyway, if it so, the compressed files will be updated; so there is no problem...

Comment: @bigTree Please run from your terminal the following commands to see the difference: `for dir in */; do echo "${dir%*/}"; done` and `for dir in */; do echo "$dir"; done`.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu *I need to compress the folders that are **not already so***

Comment: @bigTree `${dir%*/}` is the same as `$dir`, except if the value ends with a `/`, that slash is omited in the expansion.  The `*` in there is pointless and makes no difference, so it might as well be written `${dir%/}` instead to avoid confusion. So if `$dir` expands to `foo/`, then `${dir%/}` will expand to `foo`.